# Triggering ng-bootstrap modal from another component

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I’m still kind of new to Angular (using 5.x) and am having trouble wrapping my brain around using an ng-bootstrap modal.

I’ve got a datatable with a typical Delete button in it on each row (to delete that row). I want to trigger a small “Are you sure?” modal. But I can’t get it to work the way I want.

In my “PageThatHasMyDatatable.component“ I want to call the Open() method of a “MyModal.component” and have the modal display that is in the “MyModal.component”’s HTML.

I then want ”MyModal.component” to be able to detect if the modal was closed, dismissed, or if the user clicked on the backdrop (so I can log it or take an action) And after that, I want to return the result back to “PageThatHasMyDatatable.component” so it can take further action as needed.

And of course, I’m looking to reuse the same modal component for a number of various components (I just pass in the string to display in the modal and catch the Yes/No result).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Things I run across make it sound like close/dismiss/backdrop logic needs to be in the “PageThatHasMyDatatable.component” component and not the “MyModal.component”.

Anyone have an example similar to the above they could share? Or maybe point me in the right direction or something?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm looking for pretty much the same thing.  Did you work it out in the end?

Comment: Sorry, we ended up shifting the project over to using Angular Material (and a dialog box).